# Why is SSH changing my display resolution?

Tags: linux, ssh

I notice that every time I SSH into one of my headless embedded devices running Linux (an Ultra96 FPGA running Debian specifically), the display resolution of my machine changes. Not the the resolution of a monitor connected to the embedded device, but the resolution of the remote machine trying to SSH.

I think this is very weird. What might be the cause? I haven't found anything when trying to Google this, only guides on how to use SSH to modify the display resolution of a monitor connected to a remote device. Is this somehow an issue related to forwarding X?

The resolution that is being forced every time I SSH is not the same as the resolution being output to display 0 on the embedded device; it's something like 800x600. My remote machine is running Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm not sure if this is related, but the resolution of the embedded device also changes every time I locally open a terminal window on it (I haven't found the reason for this either). Might it be that the same mechanism is being triggered when I SSH, only it affects the remote machine?

Comment: Is the resolution changing, or is your display loosing sync and hiccuping? Could the issue actually be inteference in the cable between PC and monitor caused by communicating with the target device?

Comment: `ssh` almost certainly isn't changing your resolution... unless configured _very_ strangely.

Comment: This might be related to the TTY rows and columns settings. The shell startup script on the remote system might be changing the rows/columns, and the change may be propagating back to the local system's tty.